# How is this blank space coming in my website?

Tags: html, css

My HTML code:

```
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="images/favicon.ico">
    <title>Bla Bla Car Rentals - Payment</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/style.css"> <!-- Link to style.css -->
    <script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/62011a4bec.js"></script><link href="https://use.fontawesome.com/62011a4bec.css" media="all" rel="stylesheet"> <!-- Font awesome CDN -->
    <script src="js/part2.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<section class="bgimg">
    <a class="back-button" href="enquiry.html"><i class="fa fa-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></i> Back to website</a>
    <h1 class="heading">Payment</h1>
</section>
<div class="main">
    <div id="container">
        <div id="img-sec">
            <img id="car-img" src="images/bmw-m3.jpg">
        </div>
        <div id="summary-sec"><label>BMW - M3<span class="right-text"> 250AUD (per day)</span></label><br><label>Number of days <span class="right-text">X 1</span></label><br><label>Product total: <span class="right-text">250 AUD</span></label><br><label>Insurance Cover<span class="right-text">+50 AUD</span></label><br><label>Sports model<span class="right-text">+100 AUD</span></label><br><label>Snow Insurance Cover<span class="right-text">+0 AUD</span></label><br><hr><label class="grand">Total: <span class="right-text">400 AUD </span></label></div>
    </div>
</div>

</body>
```

My CSS code:

```
    body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-size:13px;
  font-weight: 300;
  position:relative;
  background-color:#2D112A;
}

    .bgimg{
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
  background: url('images/money.jpg') no-repeat center; /* Link - https://unsplash.com/collections/597225/money?photo=OCrPJce6GPk */
  background-size: cover;
  position: relative;
}
.main{
  width: 100%;
  height: 550px;
  background: #F5F5F5;
  position: relative;
  padding-top: 6%;
}

.main:before{
  content: '';
  width: 50%;
  height: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  top: -48px;
  left: 0;
  background: #F5F5F5;
  transform: skewY(6deg);
}
.main:after{
  content: '';
  width: 50%;
  height: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  top: -48px;
  right: 0;
  background: #F5F5F5;
  transform: skewY(-6deg);
}
.back-button{
  position: absolute;
  top: 8%;
  left: 3%;
  font-size: 20px;
  background: none;
  color: whitesmoke;
  border: 2px solid whitesmoke;
  border-radius: 10px;
  padding: 13px;
  cursor:pointer;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.back-button i{
  margin-right: 5px;
  font-size: 18px;
}
#container{
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 530px;
  width: 70%;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
}
#img-sec{
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  float: left;
}
#summary-sec{
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  float: left;
}
#car-img{
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
.heading{
  color: whitesmoke;
  margin: 0;
  position: relative;
  font-size: 42px;
  left: 45%;
  top: 7%;
  font-family: 'Merriweather', serif;
}
```

[image: Normal visible page]
[image: Part with unknown space]
Here is the screenshot of my website. I checked all the css for extra padding or margin but there is none.I even tried to inspect it with Google developer tools but didn't get to the source. I don't understand how is the blank space appeared on the left side of the whole page! Help would be much appreciated! Thanks

[JSFiddleLink](https://jsfiddle.net/9rok7h3q/)

Comment: can't you just right click and inspect it to see what it is?

Comment: I tried that. It is not showing anything related to it.

Comment: can you able to create a fiddle? or give you website link.

Comment: @ChiragSModi it is on a secured server wont be able to access it. I will try to make a fiddle though!

Comment: @ChiragSModi I have added the Fiddle link

Comment: @SaranshSeth check my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The problem** is in your **h1 tag css** . The `left:45%` **was causing the problem**. **So I have added the fix for that**.

```
.heading {
  color: whitesmoke;
  margin: 0;
  position: relative;
  font-size: 42px;
  /* left: 45%;*/
  top: 7%;
  font-family: 'Merriweather', serif;
  /*New Css*/
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}
```

> Hope it works perfectly for you now:) . below is the working code.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-size: 13px;
  font-weight: 300;
  position: relative;
  background-color: #2D112A;
}

.bgimg {
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
  background: url('images/money.jpg') no-repeat center;
  /* Link - https://unsplash.com/collections/597225/money?photo=OCrPJce6GPk */
  background-size: cover;
  position: relative;
}

.main {
  width: 100%;
  height: 550px;
  background: #F5F5F5;
  position: relative;
  padding-top: 6%;
}

.main:before {
  content: '';
  width: 50%;
  height: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  top: -48px;
  left: 0;
  background: #F5F5F5;
  transform: skewY(6deg);
}

.main:after {
  content: '';
  width: 50%;
  height: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  top: -48px;
  right: 0;
  background: #F5F5F5;
  transform: skewY(-6deg);
}

.back-button {
  position: absolute;
  top: 8%;
  left: 3%;
  font-size: 20px;
  background: none;
  color: whitesmoke;
  border: 2px solid whitesmoke;
  border-radius: 10px;
  padding: 13px;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.back-button i {
  margin-right: 5px;
  font-size: 18px;
}

#container {
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 530px;
  width: 70%;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
}

#img-sec {
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  float: left;
}

#summary-sec {
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  float: left;
}

#car-img {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.heading {
  color: whitesmoke;
  margin: 0;
  position: relative;
  font-size: 42px;
  /* left: 45%;*/
  top: 7%;
  font-family: 'Merriweather', serif;
  /*New Css*/
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<section class="bgimg">
  <a class="back-button" href="enquiry.html"><i class="fa fa-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></i> Back to website</a>
  <h1 class="heading">Payment</h1>
</section>
<div class="main">
  <div id="container">
    <div id="img-sec">
      <img id="car-img" src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=33&txt=350%C3%97150&w=350&h=150">
    </div>
    <div id="summary-sec"><label>BMW - M3<span class="right-text"> 250AUD (per day)</span></label><br><label>Number of days <span class="right-text">X 1</span></label><br><label>Product total: <span class="right-text">250 AUD</span></label><br><label>Insurance Cover<span class="right-text">+50 AUD</span></label><br><label>Sports model<span class="right-text">+100 AUD</span></label><br><label>Snow Insurance Cover<span class="right-text">+0 AUD</span></label><br>
      <hr><label class="grand">Total: <span class="right-text">400 AUD </span></label></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Bydefault `body` tag take some margin. If you set it to `0` then this problem will solve, You can update you `CSS` with following code

```
body {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}
```

Comment: I forgot to mention it earlier. But this is already in the css still the website has the weird spacing on left!

Comment: the problem was with some css @SuperUser

Answer (score 2):

I have a css file called page reset that I've updated over the years, you might wanna have something similar. No matter what page I'm working on, this is core thing that I always use.

```
html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, font, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    outline: 0;
    font-weight: inherit;
    font-style: inherit;
    font-size: 100%;
    font-family: inherit;
    vertical-align: baseline;
    text-decoration: none;
}
/* remember to define focus styles! */
:focus {
    outline: 0;
}
body {
    line-height: 1;
    color: black;
    background: white;
}
ol, ul {
    list-style: none;
}
/* tables still need 'cellspacing="0"' in the markup */
table {
    border-collapse: separate;
    border-spacing: 0;
}
caption, th, td {
    text-align: left;
    font-weight: normal;
}
blockquote:before, blockquote:after,
q:before, q:after {
    content: "";
}
blockquote, q {
    quotes: "" "";
}
```

Comment: Still has the spacing even after adding this code. Thanks anyways! I will use this in all projects as a head start!

Answer (score 0):

You can use universal selector and give default margin and padding values as 0px so that there will be no any unwanted margin or padding in the whole webpage.

```
* {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try to add viewport meta in your file

Insert this line in your code after the first meta tag.

`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">`

Answer (score 0):

I have one simple solution, use can just change your position type for heading class. Like this :-

```
.heading{
  color: whitesmoke;
  margin: 0;
  position: absolute;
  font-size: 42px;
  left: 45%;
  top: 7%;
  font-family: 'Merriweather', serif;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is in your `h1.heading` tag css. you have added `left:45%` was causing the problem. So I have added the fix for that. Bellow is the snippet.

```
.heading {
   color: #f5f5f5;
   font-family: "Merriweather",serif;
   font-size: 42px;
   left: 45%;
   margin: 0;
   position: relative;
   text-align: center;
   top: 7%;
}
```

> Here is the full working code. Hope this will solve you problem

```css
  body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    font-size: 13px;
    font-weight: 300;
    position: relative;
    background-color: #2D112A;
  }
  
  .bgimg {
    width: 100%;
    height: 500px;
    background: url('images/money.jpg') no-repeat center;
    /* Link - https://unsplash.com/collections/597225/money?photo=OCrPJce6GPk */
    background-size: cover;
    position: relative;
  }
  
  .main {
    width: 100%;
    height: 550px;
    background: #F5F5F5;
    position: relative;
    padding-top: 6%;
  }
  
  .main:before {
    content: '';
    width: 50%;
    height: 100px;
    position: absolute;
    top: -48px;
    left: 0;
    background: #F5F5F5;
    transform: skewY(6deg);
  }
  
  .main:after {
    content: '';
    width: 50%;
    height: 100px;
    position: absolute;
    top: -48px;
    right: 0;
    background: #F5F5F5;
    transform: skewY(-6deg);
  }
  
  .back-button {
    position: absolute;
    top: 8%;
    left: 3%;
    font-size: 20px;
    background: none;
    color: whitesmoke;
    border: 2px solid whitesmoke;
    border-radius: 10px;
    padding: 13px;
    cursor: pointer;
    text-decoration: none;
  }
  
  .back-button i {
    margin-right: 5px;
    font-size: 18px;
  }
  
  #container {
    margin: 0 auto;
    height: 530px;
    width: 70%;
    box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
  }
  
  #img-sec {
    width: 50%;
    height: 100%;
    float: left;
  }
  
  #summary-sec {
    width: 50%;
    height: 100%;
    float: left;
  }
  
  #car-img {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
  }
  
  .heading {
    color: whitesmoke;
    margin: 0;
    position: relative;
    font-size: 42px;
    /*left: 45%;*/
    text-align:center;
    top: 7%;
    font-family: 'Merriweather', serif;
  }
```

```html
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="images/favicon.ico">
<title>Bla Bla Car Rentals - Payment</title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/part2.js"></script>

<body>
  <section class="bgimg">
    <a class="back-button" href="enquiry.html"><i class="fa fa-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></i> Back to website</a>
    <h1 class="heading">Payment</h1>
  </section>
  <div class="main">
    <div id="container">
      <div id="img-sec">
        <img id="car-img" src="images/bmw-m3.jpg">
      </div>
      <div id="summary-sec">
        <label>BMW - M3<span class="right-text"> 250AUD (per day)</span></label>
        <br>
        <label>Number of days <span class="right-text">X 1</span></label>
        <br>
        <label>Product total: <span class="right-text">250 AUD</span></label>
        <br>
        <label>Insurance Cover<span class="right-text">+50 AUD</span></label>
        <br>
        <label>Sports model<span class="right-text">+100 AUD</span></label>
        <br>
        <label>Snow Insurance Cover<span class="right-text">+0 AUD</span></label>
        <br>
        <hr>
        <label class="grand">Total: <span class="right-text">400 AUD </span></label>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>
```